# Laravel 5.8: How to pass two arguements to Event & Listener

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, tron

I'm using Laravel 5.8, and I have created an Event called `UserWalletNewTransaction` that goes like this:

```
public $transaction;
public $added_type;

public function __construct($transaction, $added_type)
{
    $this->transaction = $transaction;
    $this->added_type = $added_type;
}
```

As you can see I have specified two parameters here and these parameters are getting their value from the Controller:

```
event(new UserWalletNewTransaction($newTransaction, $value_added_type));
```

And then the Listener which is named `UserWalletNotification` goes like this:

`public function handle(UserWalletNewTransaction $event, $added_type) {`

But there is something wrong here since I'm getting this error.

> Too few arguments to function
> App\Listeners\UserWalletNotification::handle(), 1 passed and exactly 2
> expected

So how to fix this issue? How can I pass two parameters to Event & Listener properly? I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Here is the error screenshot:

[image]

---

**UPDATE #1**:

Result of:

```
dump($event->added_type);
dd($event->transaction );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `UserWalltetNotification` Listener remove second param from `handle` method

so

```
public function handle(UserWalletNewTransaction $event)
{
  
   dump($event->added_type); 
   dd($event->transaction ); 

 
}
```

if you `dd($event);` you will get all properties from `UserWalletNewTransaction`

Comment: I tried that but `$added_type` variable didn't exist there. I just added an **UPDATE #1** about this.

Comment: what you gt if you dd($event->added_type);

Comment: I get this: `""`

Comment: @tejoslaeslio look like you are passing null in event(new UserWalletNewTransaction($newTransaction, $value_added_type));   but $value_added_type is null so if you pass value properly then it works as expected

Comment: Would u check this out please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68526658/session-still-submitted-after-redirecting-view